# jquery selector negative or null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any selector that do this?

Select all input field which value is negative or null.

> $('input[value<=0]') //this does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
$("input").filter(function(){
    return parseInt(this.value, 10) <=0;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sQgmQ/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). The following assumes that by "null" you mean "empty string":

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return parseInt(this.value, 10) <= 0;
});
```

This basically iterates over all elements in the matched set (so all `input` elements) and removes them from the matched set if they do not pass the test defined by the function. The test simply checks to see if the value of the `input` is less than 0, or is the empty string.

Comment: '<' should replaced with '<='

Comment: Well, your question said "negative or null". `0` is not negative. But fair enough, I will edit the answer.